# hmultiple records at once into a database in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

i’m trying to get a Repository to dave multiple records into a database simultaneously using ASP.NET code first approach. thank you in advance

Comment: what DATABASE connectivity method are you using?  and what database?

Comment: @kayode, what do you mean that save multiple records into a database at once, just insert many data into database by using code first?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 the DATABASE is a local database on my laptop.... i’m sorry if i’m not able to answer your question properly i’m using ASP.NET for the first time

Comment: @kayode, you can refer to the Microsoft doc [Tutorial: Get Started with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) to know how to use code first in asp.net.